# Display random pictures in picturebox each 0,5sec

Tags: c#

I am kinda stuck and I need help.

My goal is to make a little "game". It should have 3 pictureboxes and it should randomly display/change numbers (pictures) 1 to 6 every 0,5sec. When I hit STOP, it should stop the numbers and I should get points (score) based on nubmers. 3 same numbers = +10 points, 2 same numbers = +5 points, no same numbers = -5 points. Then it should display highest score achieved (Max Score).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tImm.png

Please, give me some tips what to do.

Thanks a lot, regards Peter

Comment: What have you done already?

Comment: Use a timer and a random number plus an Image list to set the pictures. Try something and if you encountered any problem, we are here to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with random something like this :

```
Random rnd1 = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
Image[] Images = new Image[6];
int[] CurrentStatus = new int [3];
Images[0] = Image.FromFile("FileNameFornumber1");
Images[1] = Image.FromFile("FileNameFornumber2");
Images[2] = Image.FromFile("FileNameFornumber3");
Images[3] = Image.FromFile("FileNameFornumber4");
Images[4] = Image.FromFile("FileNameFornumber5");
Images[5] = Image.FromFile("FileNameFornumber6");

//change numbers every tick
private Timer_TickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.CurrentState[0] = rnd1.Next(1, 6);
   this.CurrentState[1] = rnd1.Next(1, 6);
   this.CurrentState[2] = rnd1.Next(1, 6);
   this.PictureBox1.Image = Images[this.CurrentStatus[0]-1];
   this.PictureBox2.Image = Images[this.CurrentStatus[1]-1];
   this.PictureBox3.Image = Images[this.CurrentStatus[2]-1];
}
```

you have to write an event for the stop button to deactivate the timer and calculate the score based on the CurrentStatus Array and I think the calculation alg  must be like this :

```
int score = this.CurrentStatus.Sum();
if (this.CurrentStatus[0] == this.CurrentStatus[1] &&   this.CurrentStatus[1] == this.CurrentStatus[2])
score +=10;
else
{
   for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
       for (int j=i+1; j<3; j++)
       {
           if (this.CurrentStatus[i] == this.CurrentStatus[j])
           {
               score+=5;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for start make random picture on button press.
[How add images into resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryq8K.png)
For example

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Bitmap> picturesList = new List<Bitmap>(); //Array of pictures
    Random random = new Random(); 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Load all pictures from resources into array
        picturesList.Add(Properties.Resources.pic1);
        picturesList.Add(Properties.Resources.pic2);
        picturesList.Add(Properties.Resources.pic3);

        //Set random image into picture box
        RandomChangeImage();
    }

    public void RandomChangeImage()
    {
        //Generate random number. (random index between 0 - array.count )
        int randomIndex = random.Next(0, picturesList.Count);

        //Set random image from array
        YourPictureBoxName.Image = picturesList[randomIndex];
    }
}
```

Now you can use RandomChangeImage(); in your code. Aflter you done you can continue with timer.

Now add Timer from toolbox into designer.
Double click on timer.
It generated this

```
     private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//Call random change image
RandomChangeImage();
        }
```

in you buttonstart_Click call timer1.Start(); for example

```
 private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

if you want change tick in timer you can use 
timer1.Interval = 500; for 0.5s. where you want.

if you want stop timer use

```
timer1.Stop();
```